# Atlasian Stash and svn Integration

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

Is there a way to integrate Atlasian STASH with Subversion. 
Stash by default is used for Git. But we need to integrate it with SVN.
Please can any one help me out in understanding whether we can integrate STASH and SVN?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [SVN Mirror plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.tmatesoft.subgit.stash-svn-importer) for Stash. It links your Git repository to a remote SVN repository and keeps them in sync.